# Android: Draw ASCII Arrow on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, ascii

Is it possbile to draw a ASCII letter with following method on a canvas?

```
canvas.drawText(...)
```

Specially I want to draw the arrow up / down.

(If possibel I could avoid two pictures)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed it useing Unicode:

```
canvas.drawText("\u2191", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the question. I'm also not sure if ASCII itself has an arrow.

You definitely can draw a bunch of letters that are in the ASCII standard. Remember that Android itself uses one of the Unicodes, and Java uses UTF-16